# Can a javascript variable be used from a different file

Tags: javascript, file, var

I am making a game and I wanted to know how to use a variable from a different file. Ex:

File 1:

```
var js = "js";
```

File 2:

```
    alert(js);
```

I know it seems kind of weird but I have a reason I am doing it.

Comment: As long as you define your variable globally (`window.js = 'js';`) and it is defined before your (File 2) is referenced, you should have no problem using it.

Comment: no need to do `window.js`, `var js` is enough

Comment: @pwolaq In a global scope, yes. If defined in a function, then no.

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. It depends how you are running the JS. "Embedded in a webpage" and "In Node.JS" will give very different answers.

Comment: also be advised that polluting global scope is not a good practice, perhaps `AMD` is solution to your problem - check out `RequireJS` or some other related framework

Comment: Alright, thanks, I'll try it out =D

Comment: Javascript files are like any other file, as long as you invoke them, they will execute, therefore, if you import your file 1 BEFORE using the contents of file 1 it should be fine.
e.g in your html file:
    `<script href="file1.js"></script>`
    `<script> alert(js);</script> `

Should work as long as your browser has access to file1.js (if yopu are working on the nodejs server side, use require("moduleName") to import, but the way variables work is the same.

Comment: What if it's an array though?

Comment: Any var. `var foo=[1,2,3,4,5]; var bar = { "x":"1", "y":function() { alert(bar.x) }}`

Comment: what about functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a javascript variable be used from a different file?

Yes, it can... *As long as it's a global variable*.

This is because all of the javascript files are loaded into a shared global namespace.

#### But be warned...

In your HTML, you will need to include the script that declares this variable *first*. Otherwise it will complain that the variable is undefined.

#### Example

script1.js

```
var globalNumber = 10;
```

script2.js

```
alert(globalNumber); // Will alert "10"
```

index.html

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

Comment: What if it's an array?

Comment: @TheGamerKing The type doesn't matter, it will still work.

Comment: It worked, but I just need to know

Comment: Ok, thanks, your Idea worked @Brandon lbbotson